# Add text after bibliography list

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I have created my bibliography with Bibtex. I want to add a one-lined sentence **after the items**. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\bibliography{<bib>}` inserts the bibliography at the point where it is called. To that end, you can place it anywhere in your document, and nothing prohibits you from placing regular text before or even after it. So you can use

```
\bibliographystyle{<bibstyle>}
\bibliography{<bib>}

Here is some regular text.
```